# About the inhaling noise you make when you think of something

Tags: word-request, expressions, onomatopoeia

A paralanguage question.

1. How do you spell<sub>(I’m not sure how to put it into a word; maybe “the ‘tsssp’ sound?”)</sub> the noise you make inhaling through your clenched teeth *when you think of something*?
2. Does it have a name; what is it called?
3. Is it common for native English speakers?

I’ve just heard it in [this video](https://youtu.be/y8Fm2V6Bkjs?t=6) where American and German women are talking in English. Before I ran into this video on YouTube, I thought it was a Korean thing as I saw many Koreans made that noise, but turned out it was not.

> #### Transcription <sub><sub>of [the YouTube video “#Hololive #HololiveEnglish #HoloMyth Calli Didn't Realize The Stream Was On...”](https://youtu.be/y8Fm2V6Bkjs?t=6)</sub></sub>
>
> **Mori Calliope**: Yeah, I wonder what we should do.
>
> **Takanashi Kiara**: Umm.
>
> **Mori Calliope**: What do you think?
>
> **Takanashi Kiara**: I mean…, ______ (***the noise***), uh…, it’s, it’s kind of weird to leave it there.
>
> **Mori Calliope**: Yeah, maybe we should do—, go back and do it again.

Comment: I don't think this has a specific name in any major dialect of English.  You would have to describe the act, as in ["The deputy drew in a sharp breath of air between his teeth."](https://books.google.com/books?id=O4CaDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA62&dq=air+between+his+teeth&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcltXauNDvAhWNQc0KHccaDC84ChDoATAAegQIBhAC)

Comment: @stangdon That sounds to me like a very good answer—illustrated by real source, even! I hope you can find a moment to post it as an answer so I can vote it up.

Comment: I would call it a “sharp intake”, but I’ve only ever seen that in books, not speech. I’m not aware of a specific word.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. This one’s [a different sound](https://youtu.be/5RJLDATSbqQ) but related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/is-there-an-ipa-character-for-the-sympathetic-sucking-in-sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Chupse** might be what you're looking for. Defined by [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chupse) as ‘The sound produced by sucking air between the teeth, expressing displeasure, incredulity, etc’.

(Or *ingressive dental fricative* in phonetics.)

Comment: I'm marking this answer down only because **chupse** is an *incredibly* obscure dialect word.  (Note that Wiktionary says *(Barbados)*.)  It isn't part of the vocabulary of any other dialect as far as I can tell.

Comment: @stangdon: Sure... an *incredibly* obscure action must be described by an incredibly obscure word wouldn't you say?

Comment: I don't think the action is incredibly obscure.  If you search Google Books for things like *sucked air between teeth* you find plenty of results, it's just that most dialects of English haven't felt the need for a specific word for it.  And even if the action is obscure, I'm not sure how it helps from a communication standpoint to use a word that listeners are not going to understand or be able to find in a dictionary.